# How to CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG using flyway?

Tags: sql-server, flyway

I tried to migrate MS SQL database using flyway command line tool. But when I tried to run command CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.
```

How do I can run flyway without transaction?

P.S. I have found several same questions but all of them without answer.

Comment: Hi, frustrating as it is to find questions without answers, please don't create a duplicate if there is already a question asking this. Once you have more reputation on the site, you will have the ability to draw attention to questions in various ways, such as voting for them, or [offering a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a bug. File an issue in the Flyway issue tracker requesting support.